# Has anybody implemented Notification Applications in Mitel IP Phones?

Tags: notifications, ip, voip, telephony

I need to implement a Notification Application in Mitel IP Phones (mainly 5330 and 5360). Where can I start? I tried to have a look at the applications samples provided by the Mitel HTML Toolkit but there is no sample for the Notification App since the web server is needed.

Any guidance (tutorial, advice, sample, etc.) you could give me will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if you're trying to do a popup on the phone, or on a computer client.  The HTML Toolkit is used typically to load apps on the phones, but there's some issues depending on what phone system the 5330 and the 5360 are connected to, the 3300 for instances has better support for apps on the phones, whereas the 5000 cp does not.  The phones can be used in SIP mode which allows you the ability to do html redirect and apps easier, but then you have to pay for the sip licenses, and loose the minet functionality.   An alternative is to use the UCA client SDK, it notifies a computer of events, e.g. ringing, hang up, dialed etc. and you can then use those in dot net to integrate to other sw.  Hope this helps.